# Family Sharing iPhone syncing

Tags: iphone, itunes, family-sharing

I'm downloading family shared purchases (music) to my iPhone. It seems as though after I sync my phone to my computer it removes all the shared content I downloaded. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you can still see it on your computer in iTunes, you need to turn off your iTunes Match on your Phone and on your computer.

Disconnect and connect to refresh. Now on your phone, go to your Settings → iTunes & App Store and turn off the iTunes Match and it will give you 2 options: Enable or Cancel. Select Enable!

Then go to your computer on your iTunes, where you see your Phone, then on the menu bar where it says File, Edit, View, Control, Store and Help, go to Store and click the option where it says turn off your iTunes Match. Disconnect your Phone from the computer and connect again.